# how can I use summation and index for the series by using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, series, differential-equations, cumulative-sum, derivative

[image]

The solution  of IVP as follows.

[image]

how can I use summation and index for the pervious equation by using MATLAB.

My trying to write the following code. It is give me diverge

```
u0=0;
alpha=0.5;%[0.1 0.3 0.5 0.6 0.66 0.9 1]; matrix 
a=0; b=1;n=100;
h=(b-a)/n;
t=a:h:b;
f=@(t,u) (-u.^4) +  ( gamma(2*alpha+1)./gamma(alpha+1) ).*(t.^alpha) - ( 2./gamma(3-alpha) ).*(t.^(2-alpha)) + (t.^(2*alpha)-t.^2).^4;
exact=@(t) t.^(2*alpha)-t.^2;
%-----a'ks---------------------------------------
a_kth=@(k) (k+1).^(1-alpha)-(k).^(1-alpha);
u_p=zeros(1,n); z_p=zeros(1,n); u=zeros(1,n);
s=0;
for i=1
    u_p(i)=a_kth(i-1)*u0;    %s=s+q^keval(subs(fun,xq^k));
    z_p(i)=gamma(2-alpha)*( h.^alpha ) * f(t(i),u_p(i));
    u(i)=u_p(i)+gamma(2-alpha)*( h.^alpha ) * f(t(i),u_p(i)+z_p(i));
end
%--------------------------------------
for i=2:n
for k=1:i-1
    s=s+(a_kth(i-1-k)-a_kth(i-k))*u(k);
    u_p(i)=a_kth(i-1)*u0+s;    %s=s+q^keval(subs(fun,xq^k));
    z_p(i)=gamma(2-alpha)*( h.^alpha ) * f(t(i),u_p(i));
    u(i)=u_p(i)+gamma(2-alpha)*( h.^alpha ) * f(t(i),u_p(i)+z_p(i));
end
end
u1=[ u0 u];
plot(t,u1)
exact1=exact(t);
error=exact1-u1;
```

Comment: "I don't know if it's right or not" - you should try and create (for yourself and us) a [mcve]. You could probably work out the expected result by hand for a small `N` to give at least one case for validation of your code

Comment: @Wolfie i did it but give me div. !

Comment: I don't know what "give me div" means? Please [edit] your question to include the [mcve]

Comment: “give me diverge” is not much more useful than “give me div”. Please copy-paste the full error message, or describe the actual output you get and the expected output.

Comment: @CrisLuengo please help and guide me to get on full code

Comment: @CrisLuengo it is not give me error message but the solution is diverge with respect to correct solution, that is because there is error in my code. please help me and answer my Question

Comment: I cannot help if so don’t know what the problem is. When people comment with suggestions for how to improve your question it is not because we don’t want to help, it’s because we don’t understand the question.

Comment: So with “diverge” you mean that your result is not the expected result? Did you try running through the code line by line to see where the solution differs from your expectation? Did you try the code with a simpler problem?

Comment: @CrisLuengo i did it, but give me mixed result. Really, I am tired to the solution of IVP as above by using matlab. so, I post my Question here.  I hope helping